# streaming from Android to VLC

Tags: android, rtsp, vlc, rtp

I know similar questions have been asked but I have not been able to find the answer to my SPECIFIC problem.

I am attempting to create a RTSP/RTP video stream from the Android camera to a VLC Player client.  I have written a small RTSP server to handle all the the setup and VLC seems to like my parameters. However, after the PLAY command is issued and My app starts sending the video stream (via DatagramPackets) the VLC player does not receive any data.

I am using the jlibrtp library and setup my stream like this

```
    sendSoc = new DatagramSocket(1238);
    recSoc = new DatagramSocket(1239);
    sess = new RTPSession(sendSoc, recSoc);
    FakeClass fc = new FakeClass(); //This implements the RTPAppIntf but all the functions are empty
    sess.RTPSessionRegister(fc, null, null);
    sess.payloadType(96);
    Participant p = new Participant("localhost",1236,1237);
    sess.addParticipant(p);
```

This is the logs I see from VLC player

```
Opening connection to 192.168.1.221, port 1234...
[0xb1003790] main art finder debug: no art finder module matching "any" could be loaded
[0xb1003790] main art finder debug: TIMER module_need() : 6.331 ms - Total 6.331 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 6.331 ms)
[0x9f653e0] main playlist debug: art not found for rtsp://192.168.1.221:1234
...remote connection opened
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.221:1234 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)


Received 76 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.221:1234 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
Accept: application/sdp


Received 240 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Content-Type: application/sdp

v=0
o=- 1343306778867 1343306778867 IN IP4 192.168.1.221
s=Droid Stream
i=Live Stream from Android Camera
t=1343306778873 0
m=video 1236/2 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/9000


[0xb0101190] live555 demux debug: RTP subsession 'video/H264'
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.221:1234/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=1236-1237


Received 128 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Session: 1343306779273
Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=1236-1237;server_port=1238-1239


[0xb5203c18] main input debug: selecting program id=0
[0xb0101190] live555 demux debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
Sending request: PLAY rtsp://192.168.1.221:1234 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
Session: 1343306779273
Range: npt=0.000-


Received 71 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete PLAY response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 5
Session: 1343306779273
Range: npt=0.000-
```

.
.
[Snip]
.
.

```
[0xb5203c18] main input debug: `rtsp://192.168.1.221:1234' successfully opened
[0xb0101190] live555 demux warning: no data received in 10s. Switching to TCP
Sending request: TEARDOWN rtsp://192.168.1.221:1234 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 6
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
Session: 1343306779273
```

So I don't know what is wrong.  VLC should be listening on the android device port 1236 but its not seeing the packets so i dont know where it is listening.  Can tell me if this looks right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue was writing my packets to the Android device port 1236 instead of the client device port 1236.  So the transport parameter in the SETUP command that states

```
Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=1236-1237;server_port=1238-1239
```

Is stating the server (Android phone) will send RTP packets from server port 1238 to client device port 1236.  Likewise, RTCP communication will occur between server port 1239 and client device port 1237.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you try to check session? Does it contain packets on port 1236? Is it possible that your FakeClass must contain any functions which must send data to VLC?